# Automating Mailchimp Campaign Updates with HTML/CSS Content from Google Sheets

Tags: mailchimp, zapier

I'm working on a project where I need to automate the process of updating Mailchimp email campaigns based on data stored in a Google Spreadsheet. Specifically, I want to update the HTML/CSS content of an existing Mailchimp campaign every time a new row is added to the spreadsheet or on a weekly basis. The goal is to either directly update the campaign's code view with new HTML/CSS from the spreadsheet or find a workaround that achieves a similar result.

**Problems:**

- Direct Updates: I haven't found a way to directly update an existing Mailchimp campaign's HTML/CSS through Zapier or Mailchimp's UI. It seems like Mailchimp campaigns are structured in blocks, and there isn't an option to overwrite the entire HTML/CSS via automation tools.
- Custom Actions in Zapier: I considered using Zapier's "Custom Actions" (currently in beta) to create a solution, but I ran into issues with the beta feature not loading properly.
- Creating New Campaigns: While Zapier supports creating new campaigns, it doesn't meet my need to update an existing campaign or to easily handle HTML/CSS content directly from a Google Doc or Sheet.

**My Questions:**

- Is there a known method or best practice for automating the update process of Mailchimp campaign content (specifically HTML/CSS) using data from a Google Spreadsheet?
- Can this be achieved using Zapier, or would a direct approach with Mailchimp's API be more appropriate? If so, how would one structure such an API call to update the campaign's HTML/CSS content?
- Are there alternative tools or services that specialize in this type of automation between Google Sheets and Mailchimp, especially for direct HTML/CSS content updates?